# wolfram mathematica code vs. wolfram alfa discrepancy in calculation of common divisors? help me pls :)

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm new to coding and want to make a code in wolfram mathematica.
What I want to do is decompose a perfect number into fractions for each digit.

Example for the 2nd perfect number:
I want 28 to be written as 20/100 and 8/100. I want to do this for the bigger perfect numbers aswell so I need a general code.

Next I want to find the ammount common divisors of 20 and 100. (which is 6) and the amount of common divisors of 8 and 100 (which is 3).

Now seems simple but for bigger numbers I get discrepancies between wolfram alpha calculations and wolfram mathematica calculations.

I can't really find the problem but the list I found was:

```
1st (x)                                 3
2nd (y)                             6   3
3rd (z)                         12  4   2
4th (g)                     16  9   6   4
5th (t)     64  49  42  30  0   9   4   2
6th (r) 110 90  88  49  54  30  16  0   6   2
```

but I get a different output in mathematica. It seems that mathematica doubles some numbers and some times it just adds a few (for the 3rd number I get 12, 4, and 2 but mathematica gives me 15, 12, and 4)

The code I made up until now is:

```
(* Definieer het perfecte nummer dat u wilt analyseren *)
perfectNumber = PerfectNumber[6];

(* Converteer het perfecte nummer naar een lijst van zijn cijfers *)
digits = IntegerDigits[perfectNumber];

(* Bepaal het aantal cijfers in het perfecte nummer *)
numDigits = Length[digits];

(* Positioneer de cijfers op basis van hun plaats in het perfecte nummer *)
positionedDigits = MapIndexed[#1 10^(numDigits - #2[[1]]) &, digits];

(* Verdeel elk gepositioneerd cijfer door het aantal cijfers in het perfecte nummer *)
dividedDigits = Map[#/10^numDigits &, positionedDigits];

(* Bepaal de delers van elk gepositioneerd cijfer *)
numeratorDivisors = Map[Divisors, positionedDigits];

(* Bepaal het aantal delers van elk gepositioneerd cijfer *)
numDivisors = Map[Length, numeratorDivisors];
```